# AWS redirect www.example.com to non-AWS hosted www.example.net + URL including parameters

Tags: redirection, amazon-web-services

I'm looking for the most efficient and cost effective way of setting this up:

http://www.example.com or https://www.example.com
redirects to https://www.example.net/xyz?foo=bar&baz=qux

example.com is hosted in one of my AWS accounts and example.net is hosted by a 3rd party somewhere else.

I've thought about:

- S3 with an index.html that has a meta redirect
- micro instance that simply serves up a 301 redirect with an ALB in front
- Using cloudfront (which I don't know much about but I think this would be possible with it)

The micro instance gives the most flexibility I think but seems to be the most moving parts. There won't that many users, 400-500 tops with maybe a couple requests-per-second at peak.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where does `/xyz?foo=bar&baz=qux` come from?  Is that from the original request, or static, or ...?

Comment: It's static, not from the original request.

Answer (score 0):

Set up S3 to send a 301 redirect as per [this blog article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-support-for-website-redirects/). Here's how the documentation says to set this up.

[image]

The page I linked to confirms this sends a 301 redirect, it's not a html based redirect.